# Unexpected output of a growing dynamic array

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

I am attempting to create a dynamic array that will grow in size if needed, as I don't know how large the array will actually be. My code seems to work until the 8th element of the array where I start to see very large incorrect values that I did not enter. Not sure why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
 int val; 
 int userInput; 
 int* arr;  
 int size = 1; 
 int arrIndex = 0; 
 arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);


 /* prompt the user for input */
 printf ("Enter in a list of numbers to be stored in a dynamic array.\n");
 printf ("End the list with the terminal value of -999\n");
 
 /* loop until the user enters -999 */
 scanf ("%d", &val);
 while (val != -999)
   {
     if (arrIndex >= size)

      {
        size++; 
        
      }

    arr[arrIndex] = val; 
    arrIndex++; 

    /* get next value */
    scanf("%d", &val);
   }
    int j = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < size ; j++)
    {
        printf("%d \t", arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of the array remains 1 and doesn't increase while incrementing `size` variable.

Your code worked until 8th element because adjacent memory after the array upto 7th element must be free.
In C array index out of bound is not checked and it is programmers responibility.

if you want to increase or decrease size of array you can use `realloc` inside while loop:

```
arr=(int*)realloc(arr,sizeof(int)*size);
```

Also Correct this `if` condition in your code initially arrayindex is 0 and size is 1 which results in false.

if (arrIndex >= size)

```
  {
    size++;

  }
```